# Is it possible to get correct code coverage for solution, if projects use several test frameworks?

Tags: c#, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I have a solution with test projects using `MSTest` and `xUnit`.
I have gated build which rejects PR, if code coverage goes lower than some given level. Now it only works for `MSTest`.

I'd like to get the aggregated code coverage value from these 'heterogenious' test projects (taking into account possible overlap).

Comment: I don't know if you can do this with teamcity.  I know this is possible with other tools.

Comment: You might find this SR answer useful: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19828/101